# Android Blur effect on Finger touch

Tags: android

Hello everyone I am new to android I am developing an application in which I want to add blur effect on photo selected from Gallery or captured from camera. In my requirements I have to show blur effect on that part of photo which user touches. I searched and read tutorials and blogs and also I use github repository, but failed to find some useful information. Give me some useful tutorial or method. I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 3):

This is working code that I am using to blur a image on finger move. Wherever you will move finger that part will be blurred.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.renderscript.Allocation;
import android.renderscript.Element;
import android.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlur;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static Paint mPaint;
    public static Path mPath;
    protected Bitmap backgroundImage;
    protected static Canvas myCanvas = null;
    int dispHeight;
    int dispWidth;
    boolean flagProgress = false;
    int blurSize = 4;
    String picturePath = "";
    float Orientation;
    int MaxResolution, maxHeightResolution;
    boolean blurBoolean = false;
    private Drawable bluredImageBackground = null;
    private Button blurr;
    protected static Bitmap overlay = null;
    protected static Bitmap topBitmap = null, bottomBitmap = null;
    boolean booleanBlur = false;
    boolean booleanUndo = false;
    Button brushSizeButton;
    int buildVersion;
    int count = 0;
    boolean edited = false;
    public static Bitmap foregroundbitmap;
    int height;
    int imageheight;
    int imagwidth;
    File isfile;
    public static MyFingerTap myInvalidate;
    int pos;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    Bitmap resisedbitmap;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    Button shareButton;
    Bitmap bitmapImage;
    String shareImageFileName;
    int size = 30;
    RelativeLayout subrelativeLayout;
    View viewHorizontalRect;
    Button undoButton;
    int width;
    private SeekBar seek_bar;
    float mX, mY;
    private RelativeLayout super_layout;
    public static Bitmap bitmap;
    private ImageView mirro_image;

    // /////////////////////////////////////////
    private ImageView image_blur, image_save, image_undo, image_effect,
            image_share;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
        seek_bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
        Display localDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        localDisplay.getHeight();
        int i = localDisplay.getWidth();
        int j = localDisplay.getHeight();
        MaxResolution = i;
        imagwidth = 100;
        imageheight = 100;
        maxHeightResolution = j;
        super_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.super_layout);
        // this.picturePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
        // this.Orientation = getCameraPhotoOrientation(this.picturePath);
        // getAspectRatio(this.picturePath);
        // foregroundbitmap = getResizedOriginalBitmap(this.imagwidth,
        // this.imageheight);
        foregroundbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(SplashActivity.passBitmap,
                i, 550, true);

        if (foregroundbitmap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image not Suuported", 0)
                    .show();
            finish();

        }

        // /////////////////////////////
        topBitmap = foregroundbitmap;
        bottomBitmap = foregroundbitmap;
        overlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(foregroundbitmap.getWidth(),
                foregroundbitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        // ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        if (foregroundbitmap == null || overlay == null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "bitmap is null",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        initializePaint(20);
        seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int value, boolean arg2) {
                setpaintSize(value);

            }

        });
        callAsynk();
        super_layout.addView(new MyFingerTap(MainActivity.this));
    }

    private void init() {
        mirro_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mirro_image);
        image_blur = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_blur);
        image_save = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_save);
        image_undo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_undo);
        image_effect = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_effect);
        image_share = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_share);

        image_blur.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (super_layout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    super_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mirro_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
        image_save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (super_layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    super_layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    super_layout.buildDrawingCache();
                    Bitmap bitmap = super_layout.getDrawingCache();
                    saveBitmap(bitmap);
                } else {
                    if (passBitmap != null)
                        saveBitmap(passBitmap);
                }

            }
        });
        image_undo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callAsynk();

            }
        });
        image_effect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                applyEffect();
            }
        });
        image_share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                shareBitmap();

            }
        });

    }

    public Bitmap passBitmap;

    protected void applyEffect() {
        super_layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        super_layout.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = super_layout.getDrawingCache();
        passBitmap = BitmapProcesser.Mode_1_A(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap));
        super_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mirro_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mirro_image.setImageBitmap(passBitmap);

    }

    public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
        String _time = "";
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int millisecond = cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
        int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int hourofday = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        _time = "image_" + hourofday + "" + minute + "" + second + ""
                + millisecond + ".png";
        String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/BlurBackgroundImage";
        try {
            File dir = new File(file_path);
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(dir, _time);
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Image has been saved in BlurBackgroundImage folder",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error in saving image", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    protected void shareBitmap() {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (super_layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            super_layout.invalidate();
            super_layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            super_layout.buildDrawingCache();
            bitmap = super_layout.getDrawingCache();
        } else {
            super_layout.invalidate();
            bitmap = passBitmap;
        }
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        final File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath()
                + "/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");
        try {
            cachePath.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
            ostream.flush();
            ostream.close();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                            Uri.fromFile(new File(cachePath.getAbsolutePath())));
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }, 1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    public void callAsynk() {
        new BackgroundRunner().execute("");

    }

    public class BackgroundRunner extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected void onPostExecute(String paramString) {
            MainActivity.bottomBitmap = MainActivity.foregroundbitmap;
            MainActivity.topBitmap = MainActivity.this.backgroundImage;
            MainActivity.myCanvas.drawBitmap(MainActivity.bottomBitmap, 0.0F,
                    0.0F, null);
            MainActivity.myInvalidate.invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            MainActivity.this.backgroundImage = MainActivity.this.fastblur(
                    MainActivity.foregroundbitmap, 10);
            return null;

        }
    }

    public void initializePaint(int paramInt) {
        mPath = new Path();
        myCanvas = new Canvas();
        myCanvas.setBitmap(overlay);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        myCanvas.drawBitmap(MainActivity.foregroundbitmap, 0.0F, 0.0F, null);
        myCanvas.drawBitmap(MainActivity.foregroundbitmap, 0.0F, 0.0F, mPaint);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(paramInt);
        mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setFilterBitmap(false);

    }

    private void setpaintSize(int size) {
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(size);
    }

    private void getAspectRatio(String paramString) {
        BitmapFactory.Options localOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        localOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(paramString, localOptions);
        float f1 = localOptions.outWidth / localOptions.outHeight;
        float f3 = 0;
        float f2 = 0;
        if (f1 > 1.0F) {
            f3 = this.MaxResolution;
            f2 = f3 / f1;
        }
        while (true) {
            this.imagwidth = (int) f3;
            this.imageheight = (int) f2;
            f2 = this.MaxResolution;
            f3 = f2 * f1;
            break;
        }

    }

    public static int getCameraPhotoOrientation(String paramString) {
        try {
            int i = new ExifInterface(new File(paramString).getPath())
                    .getAttributeInt("Orientation", 1);
            switch (i) {
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 7:
            default:
                return 0;
            case 8:
                return 270;
            case 3:
                return 180;
            case 6:
            }
            return 90;
        } catch (Exception localException) {
            localException.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private Bitmap getResizedOriginalBitmap(int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options localOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            localOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(this.picturePath),
                    null, localOptions);
            int i = localOptions.outWidth;
            int j = localOptions.outHeight;
            int k = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (i / 2 <= paramInt1) {
                    float f1 = paramInt1 / i;
                    float f2 = paramInt2 / j;
                    localOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                    localOptions.inDither = false;
                    localOptions.inSampleSize = k;
                    localOptions.inScaled = false;
                    localOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                    Bitmap localBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                            new FileInputStream(this.picturePath), null,
                            localOptions);
                    Matrix localMatrix = new Matrix();
                    localMatrix.postRotate(this.Orientation);
                    return Bitmap.createBitmap(localBitmap, 0, 0,
                            localBitmap.getWidth(), localBitmap.getHeight(),
                            localMatrix, true);
                }
                i /= 2;
                j /= 2;
                k *= 2;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("this is exception", "" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Bitmap fastblur(Bitmap sentBitmap, int radius) {
        Bitmap bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);

        if (radius < 1) {
            return (null);
        }

        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();

        int[] pix = new int[w * h];
        bitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

        int wm = w - 1;
        int hm = h - 1;
        int wh = w * h;
        int div = radius + radius + 1;

        int r[] = new int[wh];
        int g[] = new int[wh];
        int b[] = new int[wh];
        int rsum, gsum, bsum, x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw;
        int vmin[] = new int[Math.max(w, h)];

        int divsum = (div + 1) >> 1;
        divsum *= divsum;
        int dv[] = new int[256 * divsum];
        for (i = 0; i < 256 * divsum; i++) {
            dv[i] = (i / divsum);
        }

        yw = yi = 0;

        int[][] stack = new int[div][3];
        int stackpointer;
        int stackstart;
        int[] sir;
        int rbs;
        int r1 = radius + 1;
        int routsum, goutsum, boutsum;
        int rinsum, ginsum, binsum;

        for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
            for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
                p = pix[yi + Math.min(wm, Math.max(i, 0))];
                sir = stack[i + radius];
                sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);
                rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);
                rsum += sir[0] * rbs;
                gsum += sir[1] * rbs;
                bsum += sir[2] * rbs;
                if (i > 0) {
                    rinsum += sir[0];
                    ginsum += sir[1];
                    binsum += sir[2];
                } else {
                    routsum += sir[0];
                    goutsum += sir[1];
                    boutsum += sir[2];
                }
            }
            stackpointer = radius;

            for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {

                r[yi] = dv[rsum];
                g[yi] = dv[gsum];
                b[yi] = dv[bsum];

                rsum -= routsum;
                gsum -= goutsum;
                bsum -= boutsum;

                stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
                sir = stack[stackstart % div];

                routsum -= sir[0];
                goutsum -= sir[1];
                boutsum -= sir[2];

                if (y == 0) {
                    vmin[x] = Math.min(x + radius + 1, wm);
                }
                p = pix[yw + vmin[x]];

                sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);

                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];

                rsum += rinsum;
                gsum += ginsum;
                bsum += binsum;

                stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
                sir = stack[(stackpointer) % div];

                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];

                rinsum -= sir[0];
                ginsum -= sir[1];
                binsum -= sir[2];

                yi++;
            }
            yw += w;
        }
        for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
            yp = -radius * w;
            for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
                yi = Math.max(0, yp) + x;

                sir = stack[i + radius];

                sir[0] = r[yi];
                sir[1] = g[yi];
                sir[2] = b[yi];

                rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);

                rsum += r[yi] * rbs;
                gsum += g[yi] * rbs;
                bsum += b[yi] * rbs;

                if (i > 0) {
                    rinsum += sir[0];
                    ginsum += sir[1];
                    binsum += sir[2];
                } else {
                    routsum += sir[0];
                    goutsum += sir[1];
                    boutsum += sir[2];
                }

                if (i < hm) {
                    yp += w;
                }
            }
            yi = x;
            stackpointer = radius;
            for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                pix[yi] = (0xff000000 & pix[yi]) | (dv[rsum] << 16)
                        | (dv[gsum] << 8) | dv[bsum];

                rsum -= routsum;
                gsum -= goutsum;
                bsum -= boutsum;

                stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
                sir = stack[stackstart % div];

                routsum -= sir[0];
                goutsum -= sir[1];
                boutsum -= sir[2];

                if (x == 0) {
                    vmin[y] = Math.min(y + r1, hm) * w;
                }
                p = x + vmin[y];

                sir[0] = r[p];
                sir[1] = g[p];
                sir[2] = b[p];

                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];

                rsum += rinsum;
                gsum += ginsum;
                bsum += binsum;

                stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
                sir = stack[stackpointer];

                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];

                rinsum -= sir[0];
                ginsum -= sir[1];
                binsum -= sir[2];

                yi += w;
            }
        }
        bitmap.setPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

        return (bitmap);
    }

    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi" })
    Bitmap BlurImage(Bitmap paramBitmap) {
        try {
            RenderScript localRenderScript = RenderScript
                    .create(getApplicationContext());
            Allocation localAllocation1 = Allocation.createFromBitmap(
                    localRenderScript, paramBitmap);
            ScriptIntrinsicBlur localScriptIntrinsicBlur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur
                    .create(localRenderScript, Element.U8_4(localRenderScript));
            localScriptIntrinsicBlur.setRadius(4.0F);
            localScriptIntrinsicBlur.setInput(localAllocation1);
            Bitmap localBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(paramBitmap.getWidth(),
                    paramBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Allocation localAllocation2 = Allocation.createFromBitmap(
                    localRenderScript, localBitmap);
            localScriptIntrinsicBlur.forEach(localAllocation2);
            localAllocation2.copyTo(localBitmap);
            localRenderScript.destroy();
            return localBitmap;
        } catch (Exception localException) {
        }
        return paramBitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap paramBitmap, int paramInt1,
            int paramInt2) {
        int i = paramBitmap.getWidth();
        int j = paramBitmap.getHeight();
        float f1 = paramInt2 / i;
        float f2 = paramInt1 / j;
        Matrix localMatrix = new Matrix();
        localMatrix.postScale(10, 10);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(paramBitmap, 0, 0, i, j, localMatrix, false);
    }

    @SuppressLint({ "ClickableViewAccessibility" })
    public static class MyFingerTap extends View {
        private static final float MAX_VAL = 4.0F;
        private Path mPath;
        private float mX;
        private float mY;

        public MyFingerTap(Context paramContext) {
            super(paramContext);
            this.mPath = new Path();
            MainActivity.myInvalidate = this;
        }

        public MyFingerTap(Context paramContext, AttributeSet paramAttributeSet) {
            super(paramContext);
            MainActivity.myInvalidate = this;
        }

        private void touchMove(float paramFloat1, float paramFloat2) {
            float f1 = Math.abs(paramFloat1 - this.mX);
            float f2 = Math.abs(paramFloat2 - this.mY);
            if ((f1 >= 4.0F) || (f2 >= 4.0F)) {
                this.mPath.quadTo(this.mX, this.mY,
                        (paramFloat1 + this.mX) / 2.0F,
                        (paramFloat2 + this.mY) / 2.0F);
                this.mX = paramFloat1;
                this.mY = paramFloat2;
            }
        }

        private void touchStart(float paramFloat1, float paramFloat2) {
            this.mPath.reset();
            this.mPath.moveTo(paramFloat1, paramFloat2);
            MainActivity.myCanvas.drawPoint(paramFloat1, paramFloat2,
                    MainActivity.mPaint);
            this.mX = paramFloat1;
            this.mY = paramFloat2;
        }

        private void touchUp() {
            this.mPath.lineTo(this.mX, this.mY);
            MainActivity.myCanvas.drawPath(this.mPath, MainActivity.mPaint);
            this.mPath.reset();

        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas paramCanvas) {
            paramCanvas.drawBitmap(MainActivity.topBitmap, 0.0F, 0.0F, null);
            MainActivity.myCanvas.drawPath(this.mPath, MainActivity.mPaint);
            paramCanvas.drawBitmap(MainActivity.overlay, 0.0F, 0.0F, null);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchStart(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touchMove(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touchUp();
                invalidate();
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg2" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/super_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mirro_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="20"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar_process"
        android:thumb="@drawable/scroll_bar2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/secondstrip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_blur"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/blur_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_undo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/undo_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_effect"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/effect_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_save"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/save" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_share"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/share_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What if Blur some area and after that i want the other area to Blur but not with same Blur value? I want to increase the blur value. i used you code and tried my best but fail, do you have any idea how to achieve this?